# MySql concat without trimming spaces

Tags: mysql, concatenation

How to concatenate without trimming the spaces?
I have a table with 2 fields

```
 State       City
 Arizona      Tucson
 California   Los Angeles
 Arizona      Tempe
```

When i do the MySql query

```
 Select concat(state,city) as newfield from statecity`
```

The spaces are gone and i get

```
 newfield
 ArizonaTucson
 CaliforniaLosAngeles
 ArizonaTempe`
```

I still need the spaces like this:

```
 newfield
 Arizona   Tucson
 CaliforniaLos Angeles
 Arizona   Tempe`
```

I've done this on other languages easily, but i can't find the answer on MySql

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have one solution!
`SELECT concat(rpad(state,20,' '),rpad(city,20,' ')) FROM`statecity`WHERE 1`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select concat(state, ', ', city) as newfield from statecity
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concat_ws ( concat with separator )

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ',state,'city')as city from statecity;
```